# Retrieving data from db only fetching last row as Json

Tags: php, mysql

I am having multiple rows in db such as 'id', 'name', 'bill' and getting them as RESTful service by json. However, I am not getting all rows data in json and only getting the last row. Can someone help me?

**Code Snippet:**

```
//Putting query in connection 
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $array = array( 'DATA'=>
            array(
                array('id'=>$row["id"], 'name'=> $row["name"], 'bill'=> $row["bill"]),
            )
        );
    }
    echo json_encode($array);
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: You could have answered this below ... not in comments. :)

Answer (score 5):

Explanation: On each while loop, you are replacing the content of `$array`. That way, when the loop ends, you end up with just the last row.

So, try using:

```
// while
$array[] = array( 'DATA'=> ...
// rest of code
```

---

---

If you want the top-most level to be `DATA`, it could be achieved using [mysqli_result::fetch_all](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) in a much **easier way**. Take a look:

```
// run query
$arr = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC); // (gotta fetch 'em all)
$arr = array('DATA' => $arr); // set the top-level part
echo json_encode($arr); // display json
```

That will output something like:

```
{
   "DATA":[
      {
         "id":5,
         "name":"Pizza",
         "bill":"$50"
      },
      {
         "id":"ANOTHER_ID",
         "name":"ANOTHER_FOOD",
         "bill":"ANOTHER_BILL"
      }
   ]
}
```

---

As side notes for the second method:

- It will return all the columns from the `SELECT`, so you might want to specify the columns you need (`SELECT id, name, bill FROM table_name` instead of `SELECT * FROM table_name`);
- You can change the column names returned in the result by using [alias](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp). That way, the returned keys become what you want them to be..